# Simplified Strong Law of Large Number by Using Truncating Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Consider $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. random variables with $E|X_i| <\infty$ and let $EX_i := \mu$ and $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Now, consider the corresponding truncated random variables $Y_k := X_k 1_{|X_k| \le k}$ and put $T_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. Show that $T_n/n \to \mu$ almost surely.

Here is my try:

Observe that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\infty  > E\left| {{X_k}} \right| = \int_0^\infty  {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > y)} dy\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{array} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int_{k - 1}^k {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > y)} dy} \\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{array} \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int_{k - 1}^k {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > k)} dy} \\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}
\end{array} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > k)\int_{k - 1}^k {dy} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > k)} \\
 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {P(\left| {{X_k}} \right| > k)}  < \infty 
\end{array}$$ By Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we can conclude that $P(\left\{ {\left| {{X_k}} \right| > k} \right\}i.o.) = 0$; hence, it implies
$$ \Rightarrow P(\left\{ {{X_k} \ne {Y_k}} \right\}i.o.) = 0$$

Now,I think I could infer that $ {\forall \omega ,\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\exists N\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}s.t.\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}k \ge N \Rightarrow {X_k(\omega)} = {Y_k(\omega)}} $. But then I failed  to go further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic lemma from analysis:

> Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ denote some sequences such that there exists some finite $N$ such that $y_n=x_n$ for every $n\geqslant N$. Then, $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\to\mu$ if and only if $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^ny_k\to\mu$.

Can you see why this answers your question? To prove the lemma, use the triangular inequality to show that, for every $n$, $$\left|\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k-\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^ny_k\right|\leqslant\frac{c}n$$ with $$ c=\sum_{k=1}^N|x_k-y_k|$$

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply @Did, so by using the lemma you mentioned, we could have $|S_n/n - T_n/n| < \varepsilon$ and since SLLN tells that $S_n/n \to \mu$ a.s.; hence we can conclude $T_n/n \to \mu?$ a.s.  If so, I was wondering what if we don't know the (original) SLLN, could we still end up with the same conclusion?

Comment: The lemma in my answer reduces the proof of the general $L^1$ SLLN to a proof that $\frac1nT_n\to\mu$ almost surely. Is your question how to prove that $\frac1nT_n\to\mu$ almost surely?

Comment: Yes, @Did. my question is how to prove $T_n/n \to \mu$ without assuming general $L^1$ SLLN.

Comment: This part is explained in @Khashaa's answer.